# Spring-data CrudRepository sometimes fetches entity with many duplicate join entities (eager)

Tags: hibernate, join, spring-data-jpa, duplicates, eager-loading

I know why duplicates can occur when joining, but there is some strange behavior which I can't explain with Spring-data's CrudRepository.

I have an entity let's say `Document`. Document has a userId and 3 ordered tabs `List<Tab>`.

```
@Entity(name = "document")
@Table(name = "document")
public class DocumentEntity extends AbstractEntity implements Document {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "document")
    @OrderBy("index ASC")
    private List<TabEntity> tabs;

    //...
}
```

I have a `DocumentRepository`:

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends CrudRepository<DocumentEntity, Long> {
    Optional<DocumentEntity> findById(final long id);

    Optional<DocumentEntity> findByIdAndUserId(final long id, final String userId);
}
```

FYI, `TabEntity` also has a Eager join relation to a set of numbers through a cross-ref-table.

When I use `findByIdAndUserId`, I get exactly one document with 3 tab-entities.
When I use `findById`, I get one document with exactly 600 tabs (263 x tab 1, 192 x tab 2, 145 x tab 3)

So I understand that because of the extra eager sub-join, the tabs are duplicated.

What I don't get is why `findByIdAndUserId` returns the correct entity and relations.

I also don't get why that many Tabs are returned and why exact 600 (there are exactly 25 rows when I execute the query manually with double join in SQL).

Does anyone know why? Is there a clean annotation/Repository solution for this? Or should I write a custom query which uses distinct?

Note: I can't use a set, because the index is important.

**UPDATE:**
I currently fixed the problem by using this:

`List<DocumentEntity> findAllById(final long id);`

and then just get the first element...

If someone knows what the difference is between fetching a list and fetching a single item, please enlighten me!